# pyqt5 QTableWidget im looking for a single when changed the text in a cell,it send previous text and current text

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I want to do an undo function,so I need to monitor the QTableWidget, when the text be changed, I will record the previous text to undo the change. Does anyone know about it?

Looking for a single when changed the text in a cell, it send previous text and current text, or how should I design a function to do that.

Comment: You can use [`QUndoCommand`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QUndoCommand.html#qundocommand)  and [`QUndoStack`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QUndoStack.html#)

Comment: If you're referring to a change done by the user (for instance, by *editing* the cell), you cannot directly do that, since any "changed" signal is emitted when the data has already changed in the model. The simplest solution could be to use a QTableView with a QStandardItemModel subclass and override its `setData()` by emitting a custom signal (other than calling the base implementation, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in feature which provides a previous value. Just implement it yourself using the `edit()` slot and the `itemChanged` signal, like in the following example.

```
table = QTableWidget()

prev_text = None
prev_edit = table.edit
def new_edit(index, *args):
    global prev_text
    prev_text = table.itemFromIndex(index).text()
    return prev_edit(index, *args)
table.edit = new_edit

def on_change(item):
    print('on change', prev_text, item.text())
table.itemChanged.connect(on_change)
```

Of course, if you derive the `QTableWidget`, it will be better to override the `edit()` slot and store the previous text as an instance variable.